# Inline Content CSS Property

Tags: css

Is it possible to use CSS's 'content' property using inline CSS something like this:

```
<p class="myclass" style=".myclass:after:content = 'my content here'">Hello There !!</p>
```

Comment: This is a little vague, could you elaborate?

Comment: might as well do `<p class="myclass">Hello There !! my content here</p>` .. why bother go the css2.1 way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Inline styles via the 'style' attribute can only be applied to the context element, without any selectors of any sort.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .myclass:after {
        content: "my content here";
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="myclass">Hello There</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use selectors in style attributes, so I would say no.

You can still put the style in the html file, like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass:after { content: 'my content here'; }
</style>
...
<foo class="myclass">Hello There!!</foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the OP wanted to generate the inline style dynamically.  Here is a kludgey php fragment (from a yii view I wrote) that uses the label property of a data model as both the id attribute and the css content:

```
$content = "<div id='".strtr($model->label,' ','_')."'><style type='text/css'>#"
. strtr($model->label,' ','_').":before {content: '".$model->label."';}</style>" 
. $this->renderPartial( '//team/_tree', array( 'models' => $model->teams ), true )
. "</div>\n" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There exists a working draft on [Syntax of CSS rules in HTML's "style" attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr).

If it works as in the WD you should be able to do something like:

```
<p class="myclass" style="{color: #C00; font-weight: bold} :after {content: 'my content here'}">Hello There !!</p>
```

Comment: Sadly I think that working draft is pretty much dead. It's not been updated since May 2002, and to my knowledge no browser has implemented it.

Comment: And as Chris says (and after I tested in fx3.5.5 and ie8) it don´t seem to work =P

Comment: this would be nice. I'm trying to use CSS in SharePoint pages without resorting to SharePoint Designer.