# Using variables within css javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Creating circles using jQuery and then filling them with a variable from an input field.

**The issue:** The variable `firstletter` is is not being displayed when 1. there's input in the input box and 2. when the result pane is clicked to generate a circle. The variable should be in the middle of the circle.

**jQuery:**

```
// making of the circles
    $('<div/>').attr({
        'id': i
    }).addClass('circle').css({
        'top': e.pageY - 75,
            'left': e.pageX - 75,
                'content': firstletter
    }).appendTo('#area');
```

`firstletter` being a variable here which I am using with the `content` css property.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/ZM7dC/

Comment: What indication do you have that there's a problem?  We might be able to help determine why it's wrong if you can describe *what* is wrong.

Comment: Updated with 'the issue', @David

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762047/inline-content-css-property

Comment: dont you what the letter to be inside the circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()` and add the `firstletter` as the content of the `div` since https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/ZM7dC/7/

```
var i = 0;
$('#area').bind('click', function (e) {

    // input stuff
    $('#jibberjabber').val(

    function (index, value) {
        var jimmy = value.substring(1);
        return jimmy;
    });

    // push letter to variable ready for circle
    var jibberjabbercontent = $('#jibberjabber').val();
    var firstletter = jibberjabbercontent.charAt(0);
    console.log(jibberjabbercontent, firstletter);

    // making of the circles
    $('<div>' + firstletter + '</div>').attr({
        'id': i
    }).addClass('circle').css({
        'top': e.pageY - 75,
            'left': e.pageX - 75
    }).appendTo('#area');
    i++;

});
```

Comment: This is slick man, great. I would suggest putting the //push letter to variable lines above the //input stuff so that it doesn't val() the input when doing the remove. Then again, my fault for including that mistake in my fiddle! Thank you

Comment: @Rob, Your code skips the first letter. And also the text is not in center of the circle.

Comment: Yeh true, I wasn't going to do the kids homework all for him :)

Answer (score 2):

Have updated the fiddle as per your requirement.

the problem is, you used `text()` instead of `val()`.

jQuery

```
$('#'+i).html('<span class="charIn">'+firstletter+'</span>');
```

css

```
.charIn{
  position:absolute;
  top:47%;
  left:46%;
 }
```

used the above code to add the letter inside the span to make the letter appear center of the cirlce.

here is the working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZM7dC/13/)

Comment: And another method and diferent css, but same result. http://jsfiddle.net/ZM7dC/15/

Answer (score 0):

Content can only be used with pseudo tags. Since the circle divs are not, the content is simply not displaying. Instead use

```
.addClass('circle').css({
    'top': e.pageY - 75,
        'left': e.pageX - 75,
}).text(firstletter).appendTo('#area');
```

Also you can't use .text to grab jibberjabber content. Instead use .val

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp):

> The `content` property is used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

You don't have either of those, so the content is going nowhere.

@RobSchmuecker The OP wants the letter to be in the center. Also, your code skips the first letter.